# DRY solution for reusing rails scope conditions in other methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In Rails 3.1, given this model:

```ruby
class Subscripion < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :active, lambda {
        where("start_date is not ? AND end_date >= ?", nil, Date.today)
    }

    def active?
      self.class.active.exists?(self)
    end
end
```

So far, this is the dry-est solution I could think of, because it does not repeat the conditions in the `active?` method.

There are two drawbacks though:

- Given a Subscription instance, no database query would be needed to determine whether it is active. We can check that based on its attributes: `!start_date.nil? && end_date >= Date.today`. The call to `exists?` results in an additional database query.
- If the initial Subscription instance was changed before calling `exists?` on the `active` scope, the result is not what we want, because `exists?` ignores the instance and directly queries the database.

Any ideas on better solutions, that still define the conditions in one place?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the active? method implementation is not good, because it will load all active subscriptions, and then look into the list for self. A better approach would be something like this:

```
def active?
  self.class.active.where(id: self.id).present?
end
```

This implementation only checks the database with a COUNT query.

In any case, I believe it would make more sense for the active? method to be with the condition you have written (!start_date.nil? && end_date >= Date.today), because it is the only way to reflect the real status of the current instance.

Comment: Using `where(id: self.id).present?` as you propose is slightly more efficient, but the only difference is that it returns a count, rather than all attributes of the resulting row.


But `exists?(self)` does *not* load all active subscriptions first. It runs almost the same query, except that instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` it results in a `SELECT 1 FROM ... LIMIT 1` query.


I agree that using `!start_date.nil? && end_date >= Date.today` is most correct for the `active?` method, but it does define the conditions that are the same for the scope twice, which is more prone to errors (in the future).